# How can I hide a component in AngularJS yet still get an external library to bind to it?

Tags: angularjs

In my code I have something similar to

```
<div ng-if="variableThatEvaluatesToFalse">
   <input id="location">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is hide a component and then show it in response to user input. However, upon my page loading I want Google Maps to attach to my input. Google Maps relies on document.getElementById('location') which is null presumably because AngularJS is 'hiding' it. I can I get document.getElementById('location') to return my input field even if it is initially hidden by the ngIf directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngIf` directive prevents elements from being included in the DOM at all.  What you would need in this case is `ngHide`, which would keep the element in the DOM.

See:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide